# Convert Ascii To Hex using VBScript

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

is there any to convert a string into Hex using Vb-script?

here there is a simple guide doing this, but it seems it works only for numbers not alphabets.

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_hex.asp

Comment: If your input string is `"abc 123"`, what do you expect as output? And what have you attempted to get it?

Comment: for "abc 123" output should be "61 62 63 20 31 32 33".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Char to UTF code in vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241130/char-to-utf-code-in-vbscript)

Comment: Try a search engine: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vbscript+string+character+code+hex

Comment: `msgbox Hex(Asc("A"))`. You have to do it character by character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
strString = "test"
strHex =""
For i=1 To Len(strString)
    strHex = strHex + Hex(Asc(Mid(strString,i,1)))
Next

WScript.Echo strHex
```

Comment: Best to use `&` instead of `+` for string concatenation. Don't make VBScript guess whether `10 + 20` should be `1020` or `30`.