# Escaping quotes in Javascript variable from Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, escaping

How can I **escape quotes using a Classic ASP variable in javascript/jQuery**? The ASP variable is taken from a DB. I'm using:

```
var goala = "<%=(goal_a)%>";
```

But obviously that appears as

```
var goala = "<p>testing "quotation" marks</p>";
```

when the page loads, which breaks the function with unexpected identifier.

edit: I'm using using jQuery not "how can I achieve this using jQuery" sorry wasn't clear.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What language are you using server-side? VBScript or JScript?

Comment: *"Using jQuery."* You can't. You have to fix it *server-side*.

Comment: Sorry I was just referring to the fact that that function was using jquery, not that i wanted a solution using jQuery, I've clarified the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked how to do this "Using jQuery." You can't. By the time jQuery would be involved, the code would already be invalid. You have to fix this **server-side**.

Classic ASP is unlikely to have anything built-in that will help you solve this in the general case.

Note that you have to handle more than just `"` characters. To successfully output text to a JavaScript string literal, you'll have to handle at least the quotes you use (`"` or `'`), line breaks, any other control characters, etc.

If you're using VBScript as your server-side language, you can use `Replace` to replace the characters you need to replace:

```vbscript
var goala = "<%=Replace(goal_a, """", "\""")%>";
```

Again, though, you'll need to build a list of the things you need to handle and work through it; e.g.

```vbscript
var goala = "<%=Replace(Replace(Replace(goal_a, """", "\"""), Chr(13), "\n"), Chr(10), "\r")%>";
```

...and so on.

If your server-side language is JScript, you can use `replace` in much the same way:

```js
var goala = "<%=goal_a.replace(/"/g, "\\\").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\n/g, "\n")%>";
```

...and so on. Note the use of regular expressions with the `g` flag so that you replace all occurrences (if you use a string for the first argument, it just replaces the first match).

Comment: Thank you, very succinct. Needed pointing towards using Replace, using it for a WYSIWYG which handles the other characters well, new line etc

Answer (score 4):

Adapting the [answer for another language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920752/1178314) gives a more robust solution:

```vbs
Function JavascriptStringEncode(text)
    If IsEmpty(text) Or text = "" Or IsNull(text) Then
        JavascriptStringEncode = text
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim i, c, encoded, charcode
    ' Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920752/1178314
    encoded = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        c = Mid(text, i, 1)
        Select Case c
            Case "'"
                encoded = encoded & "\'"
            Case """"
                encoded = encoded & "\"""
            Case "\"
                encoded = encoded & "\\"
            Case vbFormFeed
                encoded = encoded & "\f"
            Case vbLf
                encoded = encoded & "\n"
            Case vbCr
                encoded = encoded & "\r"
            Case vbTab
                encoded = encoded & "\t"
            Case "<" ' This avoids breaking a <script> content, in case the string contains "<!--" or "<script" or "</script"
                encoded = encoded & "\x3C"
            Case Else
                charcode = AscW(c)
                If charcode < 32 Or charcode > 127 Then
                    encoded = encoded & GetJavascriptUnicodeEscapedChar(charcode)
                Else
                    encoded = encoded & c
                End If
        End Select
    Next 

    JavascriptStringEncode = encoded
End Function

' Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243164/1178314
Function GetJavascriptUnicodeEscapedChar(charcode)
    charcode = Hex(charcode)
    GetJavascriptUnicodeEscapedChar = "\u" & String(4 - Len(charcode), "0") & charcode
End Function
```

It is done also with the help of this [answer on how to get the javascript unicode escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2243164/1178314), and it has the benefits explained in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921433/1178314).

Note that I have not specially escaped `"` and `'` as suggested in that other answer, because I consider that in an html "regular" context (attribute values by example), a `HTMLEncode` must be additionally done anyway, and it will take care of quotes (and of ampersands, ...).
`<` is still specially handled due to the `<script>` context case, where `HTMLEncode` cannot be used (it won't be html decoded from the Javascript code standpoint, when used inside a `<script>` tag). See [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) for more on the `<script>` case.

Of course, a way better solution is to avoid putting any Javascript directly in the HTML, but have it all in separated Javascript files. Data should be given through `data-` attributes on html tags.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while I dealt with this stuff.
You have to encode your data to use it inside an attribute.
Try this.

```
<%=server.HTMLEncode(goal_a)%>
```