# How to convert accented character to Hexadecimal Unicode in VBScript?

Tags: regex, unicode, vbscript, asp-classic

In VBScript, I am trying to find a way to convert accented characters of a string, in their Unicode notation.
For example, I need `ú` to be converted to `\u00FA` (cf. https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web2/action/appb_01.htm)

How could I proceed? I have been struggling without success with the `Hex()` and `AscW()` functions...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Char to UTF code in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241130/char-to-utf-code-in-vbscript). Searching would have been a start.

Comment: This is an answer, and the good one. I just stumbled upon it, and ADDED a comment to make it work. I searched A LOT, thanks for the common suggestion.

Comment: Maybe your [Google Foo](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01Qd8oVQ1HC3if3kl4Dy2Du0aGevg%3A1591878568496&source=hp&ei=qCPiXpa3HL-c1fAPqvS5mAY&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+unicode+hex+code&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbscript+unicode+hex+code&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFDRCFjRCGCsEmgAcAB4AIABO4gBO5IBATGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiWq-Xk4fnpAhU_ThUIHSp6DmMQ4dUDCA0) needs some work, I just used `site:stackoverflow.com vbscript unicode hex code` and it was within the top 10 results, took 2 minutes.

Comment: Yes, I know I suck. My apologizes. This is true that noone has never found a solution to its fresh question just a couple of minutes after posting it, and did not had the time to remove/correct its question before being pwned by moderators. I know I am the first person ever, and I know I suck for that reason. Now going to hide myself for years in the deep woods.

Comment: Seriously, that is not the intention. Just please use a bit of Google Foo before posting that’s all, no need to react like that. Hopefully you found the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, as I replied here in this thread, the suggested answer is precisely the one that I found a couple of minutes after posting this question. Everything is OK